# Правильно используйте хук. В чем проблема? Dispatch react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

После нажатия на кнопку входа, в консоли выходит ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция по входу в систему

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const response = await AuthService.login(email, password);
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
        console.log(response)
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_AUTH', payload: true})
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_USER', payload: response.data.user})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Компонент для входа в систему

```
const LoginForm = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                value={email}
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                value={password}
            />
            <button onClick={()=> login(email, password)}>Войти</button>
            <button onClick={()=> registration(email, password)}>Регистрация</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Store

```
export const store = createStore(loginReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Экшен

```
const defaultState = {
    isAuth: false,
    isLoading: false,
    user: {},
}

export const loginReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_USER':
            return {...state, user: action.payload}
        case 'LOGIN_AUTH':
            return {...state, isAuth: action.payload}
        case 'LOGIN_LOADING':
            return {...state, isLoading: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно прочитав документацию понял одну простую истину.
Нужно использовать хуки лишь в функциональном компоненте...
Саму же функцию написал по принципу ООП...

Comment: Не забудьте отметить этот ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста вопроса

Comment: @4500zenja OK...